# $\mathbb{Z}_p$ necessarily realised as galois group of characteristic $p$ field?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, positive-characteristic

Question I want to ask is practically precisely what's in the question but I will restate to make it clearer.

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$ which is not algebraically closed. Then we know that $k$ has an infinite absolute galois group by Artin-Schreier. But does the absolute galois group $G$ of $k$ necessarily contain $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if the $p$-part of $G$ is not trivial?

---

Now I believe this to be true by generalisation of Artin-Schreier (different one to the one I have just mentioned) by Witt. This basically says as long as there exists $x\in k$ such that $x$ is not of the form $\mathscr{y}=y^p-y$ for some $y\in k$, then there exists a cyclic extension of degree $p^n$ for all $n$ which would prove my statement. However I am currently not sure whether this argument really works and I'm trying to think of a case where $k=\mathscr{P}k$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_p$ do you mean the field with $p$ elements? In which case the answer is yes, as it is the subfield generated by $1$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_p$, as always it means the $p$-adic integer; but my last sentence was completely wrong so thanks for pointing out (which is fixed now).

Comment: Ahh, I thought you could not possibly mean that given the original version of the question. But do you mean as an additive group then?

Comment: yes..if I meant the multiplicative structure I would have said $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.

Comment: Right, reading the formulation again from the start this is clear (I was originally thinking in terms of rings due to the original formulation, and then I got confused how a ring would turn up in the Galois group).

Comment: Hmm, my immediate guess is that this must be true, as it should appear as the directed limit of taking extensions of degree $p$ repeatedly. But I might be missing some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogue of Kummer's theory for a field $k$ of characteristic $p$ is the Artin-Schreier-Witt theory. It allows in particular to describe the Galois group $G_p$ of the maximal abelian pro-$p$-extension of $k$ in terms of the ring of Witt vectors $W(k)$ and the Artin-Schreier operator $P$. More precisely, $G_p$ is topologically isomorphic to $Hom(W(k)/P(W(k)), W(F_p))$. Noting that $W(F_p)$ is topologically isomorphic to $Z_p$, you get all the $Z_p$-extensions of $k$ .

Unfortunately I know of no book form account of the ASW theory. Perhaps the best introduction for beginners is the first chapter of Lara Thomas' thesis  "Arithmétique des extensions d'ASW " , Univ. Toulouse Le Mirail .

Comment: I know the result you have mentioned but I am struggling to see the second part of your argument (ie the part you simply wrote 'you get all the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extensions of $k$). I do understand I am being a little slow though. Also does it imply for all $k$ (which has $G_p\neq 0$ it is necessary that $k$ has $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension or not?

Comment: The composite of all the Z_p-extensions of k is obviously contained in its maximal abelian pro-p-extension. Conversely, the fixed field of the kernel of any non trivial element f (any "character") of the Hom group above is a Z_p-extension of k, because the image of f is a non trivial subgroup of Z_p, and any such subgroup is isomorphic to Z_p . In addition, via Nakayama's lemma, the ASW description above shows that the minimal number of topological generators of G_p ( = the number of "independent" Z_p extensions) is equal to the dimension over F_p of k/P(k) .